# Is it possible using the Smile ML library to retrain a model once new training examples arrive?

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, smile

I am using the [Smile](http://haifengl.github.io/smile/regression.html) library in Scala (similar story holds in Java) to compute a linear regression model of some training examples. I create the model using the ridge function.

```
val x = readCsv._1 // contains the features
val y = readCsv._2 // contains the label

val model = ridge(x, y, 0.0057)
```

My question: is it possible to retrain such a model using new labeled training examples or do the old ones have to be included in the retraining as well?